# JRuby OJDBC, no error but insert doesn't show up?

Tags: java, ruby, jdbc, oracle11g, jruby

I've been following the [tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/jruby-oracle11g-330825.html) from Oracle, using their JDBC driver with an oracle database and JRuby. I have the JRuby connector class required, and I modified some of their code. I just want to do a simple insert statement and execute it from my script. I may have to do this 10+ thousand times once this is done.

I'm using an oracle database, 11g. CentOS 7.2 x64.

This is the code I have that is doing the work:

```
def insert_row
insert_stmt = nil
begin
  conn = OracleConnection.create(@dbuser, @dbpass, @dburl)

  insert_sql = <<-EOH
INSERT INTO TESTTABLE2(COLUMN1)
VALUES('JRUBY')
  EOH
  puts insert_sql
  insert_stmt = conn.prepare_statement(insert_sql)
  insert_stmt.execute

rescue
  puts "\n** Error occured **\n"
  puts "Failed executing Oracle demo from JRuby ", $!, "\n"
ensure
  # We have to ensure everything is closed here.
  if (!insert_stmt.nil?)
    insert_stmt.close
  end
end
end
```

The code seems to finish successfully, but doesn't actually do anything. I just copied and pasted the jdbc_connector.rb file and required it, I assumed that's how you're supposed to use that since it's just for posting to the db.

These are my settings:
init = CSVParse.new("SYSTEM", "Password", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@***.***.***.***:1521:XE")

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the sample code from the link you provided, then it has `@conn.auto_commit = false` somewhere in your code, and the example shows the use of `conn.commit` right after the `insert_stmt.execute`, so that's very likely what you need to do.

In short, add missing `conn.commit` call.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about that. I had spent all morning trying to figure that out and I just found that after I posted on here. Thank you though.